# Linq Query To Group All Other Than Top 3

Tags: c#, linq

I have the following code in Linq, and I was wondering how to make it so that it groups all others beside the top 3 into an others category and sum their volumes.

```
var list = (from t in sortedCollection.DataItem
           orderby t.volume
           select t).Take(3);
```

Comment: What do you mean by "groups"?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to use `Skip`  to ignore top 3 and group the rest like:

```
var list = (from t in sortedCollection.DataItem
           orderby t.volume
           select t).Skip(3);
```

From the comments, it seems you only want to get the sum of a particular field after skipping first 3 records.

```
var sum = (from t in sortedCollection.DataItem
           orderby t.volume
           select t).Skip(3).Sum(r=> r.VOLUME);
```

Or with a complete method syntax:

```
var Sum = sortedCollection.DateItem.OrderBy(t => t.volume)
                    .Skip(3)
                    .Sum(r=> r.volume);
```

---

If you need grouping , that it would look like:

With method syntax it should be something like:

```
var query = sortedCollection.DateItem.OrderBy(t => t.volume)
                    .Skip(3)
                    .GroupBy(t => t.YourGroupingField);
```

To do `Sum` based on a field you can do something like:

```
var query = sortedCollection.DateItem.OrderBy(t => t.volume)
                    .Skip(3)
                    .GroupBy(t => t.YourGroupingField)
                    .Select(grp => new SqlCommand(
                    {
                        Key = grp.Key, 
                        Sum = grp.Sum(r=> r.ValueFieldForSum)
                    }));
```

Comment: How would I group them?

Comment: @Sean, you can do `list.GroupBy(t=> t.YourField)`, or add `GroupBy` in your query at the end, or completely use method syntax instead of mixing query and method syntax.

Comment: But I don't want to groupby a certain field. I want to group them all together.

Comment: @Sean, umm What ? What do you mean group by all together ? do you want `Sum` of field for the rest of the list ?

Comment: Yes, I want to do a sum for the rest of the list. I figured out how to do that from the rest of your code. However, the resulted var list doesn't have a field Name that I can change (ie it isn't a single DataItem).

                var list = (from t in this.Items
                            orderby t.VOLUME
                            select t).Skip(3)
                            .Sum(item => item.VOLUME);

Comment: @Sean, The resultant list would be the `Sum` of all values. It will not have any `DataItem` with it. It can't be a single `DataItem` it is a **Sum** of all values.

Comment: I just realized that. Thank you. I have the solution I need now!